Resolving ImportError and AttributeError in Python 3.10 for Metrics Collection Scripts
I am currently upgrading our system to Python 3.10 and have encountered issues with our metrics collection scripts, specifically with standard library imports and attributes that have become problematic post-upgrade. Here’s a concise overview:
Initial ImportError:
Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'

Context. This occurs in our script that uses the pathlib module, which tries to import Sequence directly from collections—a method deprecated in Python 3.10, which now requires importing from collections.abc.
Subsequent AttributeError:
Error: AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'

Context. After updating the import to from collections.abc import Sequence, the next error arises in the typing module related to the Callable class.
Given these issues:

Could someone advise on the best practices for handling these changes without directly modifying Python's standard library files?

What are the recommended strategies for ensuring that our code is compatible with Python 3.10 and future-proof against such deprecations?


I am looking for guidance that helps maintain stability, security, and maintainability across various deployment environments. Thank you for your insights!
